# In a moderncv letter, how to increase the vertical space between the body of letter and the footer?

Tags: moderncv, letters

In a letter with class `moderncv`, when the body of letter is long enough to go to the next page, there is not enough space between the body of letter and the footer in the first page. So how to increase the vertical space between the body of letter and the footer where there is my contact details? Here is my letter:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}      
\moderncvstyle{casual}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                      
\usepackage[scale=0.95, top=1cm, bottom=2cm, left=4cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries}
\name{John}{Templeton}
\title{Resumé title}                             
\address{36 Mauniour, Valybir, Alcansa}{}{United States}
\phone[mobile]{+19193433283}                  
\email{rre8wwtrni@gmail.com}    
\extrainfo{\emailsymbol\emaillink{r\_ratreei@epi.ac.us}}

\newlength{\currentparskip}

\begin{document}

\recipient{Department of Philology \\
Faculty of Humanities \\
University California\\
Elgsdelaan 1105 \\
1081 HV California\\
M.h.vertt@mi.us\\
Job number:5675}{}

\date{\today}


\opening{To whom it may concern,}
\closing{Yours sincerely,\vspace{-0.5cm}}
\makelettertitle
\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}
    \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}

The body of the letter

\vspace{0.5cm}

\enclosure [\upshape Attached]{\upshape resume, writing sample.}      

\makeletterclosing

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase the vertical space between the body of letter and the footer just change  the given space in `geometry` for option `button` (for example from 2cm to 2.5cm).

```
\usepackage[scale=0.95, top=1cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=4cm, right=3cm,showframe]{geometry} 
%                                       ^^^^^  <========================
```

Saw you the warning after compiling that your footskip is to small.  Change it with

```
\setlength{\footskip}{45pt}
```

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.95, top=1cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=4cm, right=3cm,showframe]{geometry} 
%                                       ^^^^^  <========================

\usepackage{blindtext}

%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{45pt} % <=========================================


\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries}
% personal data
\name{John}{Templeton}
\title{Resumé title}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{36 Mauniour, Valybir, Alcansa}{}{United States}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+19193433283}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{rrewwtrni@gmail.com}    
\extrainfo{\emailsymbol\emaillink{r\_ratreei@epi.ac.us}}

\newlength{\currentparskip}

\begin{document}
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data



\recipient{Department of Philology \\
Faculty of Humanities \\
University California\\
Elgsdelaan 1105 \\
1081 HV California\\
M.h.vertt@mi.us\\
Job number:5675}{}

\date{\today}


\opening{To whom it may concern,}
\closing{Yours sincerely,\vspace{-0.5cm}}
\makelettertitle
\setlength{\currentparskip}{\parskip}% save the value of paragraph spacing

    \setlength{\parskip}{\currentparskip}% restore the value    


The body of the letter

\blindtext

\vspace{0.5cm}

\enclosure [\upshape Attached]{\upshape resume, writing sample.}


\makeletterclosing

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

you will get the result:

[image]

Comment: Bigger number for bottom brings the footer upper too. The \setlength command does not push the footer downer.

Comment: @user157323 The command `setlength{\footskip}{xpt}` changes the position of the footer, if `xpt` is not greater than the needed heigth of the footer.  Because the needed heigth is `36pt` plus a little space you change the position with `45pt` but not with `50pt`.  Just try it out for your needs ...